# biblatex \printbibliography without linebreak

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, moderncv

I'm trying to include real citation to my cv which works well except that the bibliography starts with a linebreak.

How can I remove that?

Hers my minimal tex:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       

% character encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}            

\usepackage[
  babel,
  german=quotes
]{csquotes}

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
%   hidelinks, %printig
  linkcolor=gray,
  urlcolor=blue
}}


\usepackage[
  backend=biber,      
  style=apa,           
  sortcites=true,       
  sorting=nyt,          
  hyperref=true,        
  backref=true,         
  alldates=iso8601      
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./biblatex.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\section{normal layout}


\cvline{2006}{what the layout normaly looks like}

\section{worng layout with a unwanted bonus row}

\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2006}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2007}
  \cvline{all}{\printbibliography[heading=none]}
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

heres the biblatex.bib:

```
@article{zongker_chicken_2006,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{zongker_chicken_2007,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2007}
}
```

What I get and what I want :
[image]

Comment: Well, the bibliography sensibly starts a new section of some type, so the space is unsurprising, really. And `moderncv` is inflexible and meant for boilerplate CVs, so perhaps a cheap hack like `\cvline{all}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}\printbibliography[heading=none]}` is permitted.

Comment: I would use `\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2006}`  instead of  `\printbibliography`

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and not guaranteed. As jon mentioned in comments, this is not really supported.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  babel,
  german=quotes
]{csquotes}

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=gray,
  urlcolor=blue
}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{cvbiblist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[cvbiblist]{label=, leftmargin=\bibhang, labelindent=0pt, listparindent=0pt, itemindent=-\leftmargin, itemsep=\bibitemsep, parsep=\bibparsep}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  sortcites=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  alldates=iso8601
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zongker_chicken_2006,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{zongker_chicken_2007,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\defbibenvironment{cvbib}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}\begin{cvbiblist}}{\end{cvbiblist}}{\item}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\section{normal layout}
\cvline{2006}{what the layout normaly looks like}

\section{worng layout with a unwanted bonus row}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2006}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2007}
  \cvline{all}{%
    \printbibliography[env=cvbib,heading=none]%
  }
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: hacked CV]

I'm not sure whether `enumitem` is doing a lot, to be honest. I thought I might be able to adjust the vertical spacing with it, but can't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

I used the method provided by cfr and Ulrike Fischer and modified it a bit, because enumitem would mess up the rest of the text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  babel,
  german=quotes
]{csquotes}

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=gray,
  urlcolor=blue
}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  sortcites=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  alldates=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zongker_chicken_2006,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{zongker_chicken_2007,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\section{normal layout}
\cvline{2006}{what the layout normaly looks like}

\section{first method by cfr}
\begin{refsection}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2006}
  \nocite{zongker_chicken_2007}
  \cvline{all}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip} \printbibliography[heading=none]
  }
\end{refsection}


\section{ second method by Ulrike Fischer}
\cvline{all}{\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2006}}
\cvline{   }{\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2006}}


\end{document}
```

and this is the output:
[image: output]